# How the sum() function works in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
sum({'x':-10,'y':-20,'z':-30},60) 
#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

but

```
sum({-10: 'x', -20: 'y', -30: 'z'},60)  
#returns 0
```

Comment: When you iterate over a dictionary you iterate over its keys. This is demonstrated by the examples you've posted.

Comment: sum([4],[1,2,3])  #why this error message appears:TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: Because it's trying to do `[1, 2, 3] + 4`, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can we able to add the contents of two lists using sum method; just like, [1,2,3] add [4] results to 10?

Comment: Not just using sum once, no; you'd need to combine the lists *then* sum them, e.g.: `sum([1, 2, 3] + [4])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained on [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum), the sum function will sum the `start` value (2nd argument) with the items from an iterable data structure (1st argument). And, as mentioned on the comments, a `dict` by default is iterable over its keys.

Thus, your second example is adding **60** (your start value) with your numerical dict items (keys):

> >>> 60 + (-10) + (-20) + (-30)
>
> 0

Your first example, however, is trying to add `string`s to numbers, which is not what `sum()` was intended to do:

> >>> 60 + 'x' + 'y' + 'z'
>
> (...) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

If you want, for instance, to iterate a dict over its values you can use the `values()` function. For example:

```
sum({'x':-10,'y':-20,'z':-30}.values(),60)
```

Comment: Thanq. So nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `sum({'x':-10,'y':-20,'z':-30},60)` will result in an error as the program will encounter strings instead of integers as keys. Obviously, the program won't add 60 to strings as that operation doesn't make any sense. What is the result of 'x' + 'y', 'z' + 60?

In the second example,`sum({-10: 'x', -20: 'y', -30: 'z'},60)`  the program iterates over integers only. That's why you have received 0 as the sum of -10, -20, -30 + 60 = 0. That makes sense.

Hope this helps.